# What is '~' used for in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In c++ what does a tilde “~” before a function name signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395506/in-c-what-does-a-tilde-before-a-function-name-signify)

What is the difference between the line with the ~ and the other line?

```
public:    
       myClass() {};    
       ~myClass() {};
```

Comment: What book or tutorial are you using to learn C++?

Comment: Bit of a harsh downvote really. Searching for `c++ ~` on google doesn't yield anything useful.

Comment: Let me echo @Greg -- get yourself a good C++ book, read it, and learn from it. You can start with this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: It means Destructor. You better find a good C++ book like ones advised by SO

Comment: @Josh: Reading your C++ book does, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28449088/563329

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myClass(){}` is called constructor and `~myClass(){}` is called destructor!

Constructor is invoked when an object is created, and destructor is invoked when an object is destroyed.

```
myClass *pObj = new myClass(); //constructor is invoked;
//work with pObj;

delete pObj; //destructor is invoked;
```

That is an example when you use `new` and `delete`. `new` causes constructor to be invoked, and `delete` causes destructor to be invoked.

Lets see another example:

```
{
    myClass Obj; //constructor is automatically invoked;
  //work with Obj;


} //<--here Obj goes out of scope which causes destructor to be automatically invoked;
```

With an automatic object, constructor is automatically invoked, and when the object goes out of scope, the destructor is automatically invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The function "myClass" is a constructor and is invoked when an object of that type is created. A class can provide multiple different constructors that can be used to create (i.e. construct) objects of that type.

The function "~myClass" is a destructor and is invoked when an object of that type is destroyed (which occurs when an automatic storage-allocated instance goes out of scope or when a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of that type has been deleted using the `delete` operator). Whereas a class can provide multiple constructors, a class can only provide a single destructor.

When a class has virtual methods, the destructor should also be marked virtual.