# what does the wiggle sign mean in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c

```
if (~mask == 0){...}
```

I have encountered this thing in one of the .cpp files, and I wonder what is does ~ mean in c/c++?

Comment: It's called tilde. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Computer_languages

Comment: If you're not familiar with bitwise-operations, that's a good place to start reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It's a [*tilde*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Computer_languages) and in C++ it means [*bitwise NOT*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT).**

For an eight-bit unsigned integer named `mask` with the following bit representation:

```
0010 1100
```

the value of `~mask` is:

```
1101 0011
```

Notice how all the bits have been flipped.

For your `if` condition (`~mask == 0`) to evaluate to true:

```
~mask: 0000 0000
 mask: 1111 1111
```

In such a case, `mask` has the value `255`.

Apply the same logic to integers of different bit-widths and signedness, as appropriate.

<sup>(**Note:** In reality, if your system has 32-bit `int`s, `~mask` will be 32-bit even if `mask` was 8-bit. This is because `~` performs *integral promotion*. However, I ignore this fact for the above simple examples.)</sup>

---

Here's the formal definition:

> `[C++11: 5.3.1/10]:` **The operand of `˜` shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type; the result is the one’s complement of its operand.** Integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand. There is an ambiguity in the *unary-expression* `˜X()`, where `X` is a *class-name* or *decltype-specifier*. The ambiguity is resolved in favor of treating `˜` as a unary complement rather than treating `˜X` as referring to a destructor.

As the passage reminds us, do not confuse *bitwise NOT* for [the leading character in the name of a class destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395506/in-c-what-does-a-tilde-before-a-function-name-signify). It's interesting that `~` was chosen for destructors; arguably it's because one could perceive a destructor as the opposite (i.e. logical *NOT*) of a constructor.

Answer (score 4):

it's a bitwise not. It inverts all of the bits of the variable.
In this case your if will be true if all of the bits of "mask" are 1.

Comment: Nice answer. I might just suggest including a link to some background reading on bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the *bitwise complement operator* in C.

It inverts all bits of the (promoted) operand (a `0` becomes a `1` and a `1` becomes a `0`).

```
if (~mask == 0){...}
```

This checks if all bits of `mask` are set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a bitwise not operation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT)

(And it's called a "tilde".)

Answer (score 0):

its bitwise not....it gives the complement of the given number's binary representation!
like if you write
    b=(~a);
and a is equal to say 11 whose binary representation is 0000 1011...the it'll gives
...b=1111 0100 in binary