# Call by reference with QVector

Tags: qt, reference, vector

I have in an Object an QVector of Coordinates (my type) that I want to transfer to an other Vector ( I validate and than want to use ist ).

Header

```
bool getVector(QVector<Coordinates> &getCoordinates );
```

C File

```
static QVector<Coordinates> current;


int getVector( QVector<Coordinates> &getCoordinates)
{

.... stuff ...

 getCoordinates = current;

.... stuff ....
return 0;
}
```

And I use it like

```
....

QVector<Coordinates> currentCoordinates;
getVector(currentCoordinates);

currentCoordinates.X // CRASH
```

The debugger goes to this line where an Live Crash happens

```
  inline QVector(const QVector<T> &v) : d(v.d) { d->ref.ref(); if (!d->sharable) detach_helper(); }
```

So my how can I fix this? As I can use this to get all the other Variables with this methode.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause of your problem is that `current` has not been constructed before `getVector` is called.  Initialization of static objects in C++ is a thorny area, and a frequent source of bugs - for more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order), and [the static initialization order fiasco FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12).

A simple solution to this problem is to provide access to `current` via a function, i.e. replace

```
static QVector<Coordinates> current;
```

with

```
static QVector<Coordinates>& getCurrent()
{
    static QVector<Coordinates> current;
    return current;
}
```

Note, however, that the function as written above is not thread-safe. If multiple threads may call `getCurrent`, then it should be protected with a `QMutex`.

Comment: I did what you said. It worked just fine.
But than i was told, that if i just change QVector<Coordinates> to an own Type like typdef QVector<Coordinate> VesselCoordinates, that i should work.  And it work just fine as well. Even as i was deleting your Function it still worked just fine.

thank you

Comment: @Thomas, just using a typedef should not change the behaviour of the program at all - it is just 'syntatic sugar' for the compiler.  Are you sure that just adding a typedef to your original program fixes the crash?

Comment: yes just the typedef fixed it. 
As i was told it makes that the compiler resolve it just in time and  than the Vector is been constructed. 
We trick the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For gareth and the Forum :

the header:

```
typedef  QVector<Coordinates> VesselCoordinates;

  bool (*getVessel)(Charakter forCharakter, Vessel& getVessel,VesselCoordinates &getCoordinates );
```

later i bind tis function pointer to an static function ( cause this part of my Program will be one day convertet to c)

cpp file lower layer:

```
     static struct {
            Charakter currentPlayerVessel;
            VesselCoordinates possibility;
        }data;
         static bool getVessel(Charakter forCharakter, Vessel& getVessel,VesselCoordinates &getCoordinates );

// funktion to bind the funktion pointer to this static funktion so it can be called outside the File

        static bool serverNamespace::getVessel(Charakter forCharakter, Vessel& getVessel,VesselCoordinates &getCoordinates )
        {
            bool retValue= false;

            if ( forCharakter == data.currentPlayerVessel){
                // TODO abfragen ob die Adresse regestriert ist!
                if ((true == minSize()) and  ((true == shipsInRow())or (true == shipsInLine())))
            {
                retValue = true;
                Vessel test = (Vessel)data.possibility.size();
                getVessel =  test;
                getCoordinates = data.possibility;
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }
```

And then i can use this in the upper layer cpp file to get the information i need:

```
// in an Funktion : 

 VesselCoordinates currentCoordinates;
    currentCoordinates.clear();

    Vessel currentVessel;

if (true == basicFleet->getVessel(currentCharakter,currentVessel, currentCoordinates ))

// doing stuff to it
```

so its worik fine but your idea worked just as fine. Maybe you can see why my idea is also working.

Thank you

elektor