# Boost lock_guard<boost::mutex> Throws EINVAL Exception

Tags: exception, boost, locking

I have some static user data like:

```
private:
    static std::map<unsigned long, UserDataSharedPtr> userStore_;
    static boost::mutex                               mutexUserData;

public:
    static void RemoveUserData(unsigned long id)
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutexUserData);
        std::map<unsigned long, UserDataSharedPtr>::iterator it = userStore_.find(id);
        if (it != userStore_.end())
        {
            userStore_.erase(it);
        }
    }
    static void AddUserData(unsigned long id, UserDataSharedPtr ud)
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutexUserData);
        userStore_.insert(std::make_pair(id, ud));
    }
```

And in a load testing, my program crashes at the line:

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutexUserData);
```

With exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
```

The Call Stack:

```
boost::mutex::lock() at mutex.hpp:55 0x81aeb22  
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>::lock_guard() at locks.hpp:257 0x81b2cb3    
..........RemoveUserData() at ..............:69 0x81b0b28
```

And the `boost::mutex::lock()` at mutex.hpp

```
pthread_mutex_t m;
void lock()
{
    int const res=pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    if(res)
    {
        boost::throw_exception(lock_error(res));
    }
}
```

Here `pthread_mutex_lock(&m)` returns 22, and I check 22 is `EINVAL`: `The mutex was created with the protocol attribute having the value PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT and the calling thread's priority is higher than the mutex's current priority ceiling`

What should I do?

I googled a lot, but I got no luck.

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the error is much more likely to be this one:

> The pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_trylock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() functions may fail if:
>
> [EINVAL]
> The value specified by mutex does not refer to an initialised mutex object.

This is usually caused by memory corruption. You can try running under `valgrind` or a similar tool.

Comment: hmmm, I got EINVAL explanation from: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

Comment: the exception can only be thrown when I do the load testing.  If I use valgrind, I suspect it's gonna be super slow, and valgrind will definitely affect the program itself.  but I will try it.

Comment: @Peter Lee: Read down two more lines on that page.

Comment: oops, sorry. I saw it.  hmmm.  Memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess you are running into the initialization order of statics issue, when `AddUserData` or `RemoveUserData` invoked from different compilation units. The issue I ran into when reviewing a singleton implementation [here, with a link to a workaround](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40205/a-parametrized-config-singleton?noredirect=1#comment67818_40205), also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order).