# Is it possible to check whether a static variable has been initialized yet in C++?

Tags: c++

Based on the answer to this question [C++ static initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order), it seems impossible to control the order of static initialization directly. 
However, suppose I were to explicit initialize static variables inside the constructor for a statically initialized object `foo` which depended on a different global object `bar`. Is there a way for the constructor of `foo`, on invocation, to determine whether `bar` had already been initialized statically?

That is, suppose I have in one compilation unit.

```
Foo::Foo() {
// Can I check here whether bar has already been initialized?

// do something that needs bar to be initialized
// If bar has not been initialized, then I will crash and burn.
}

// statically initialized foo
Foo foo;
```

In a different compilation unit:

```
Bar bar;
```

The goal is to make sure that `bar` is initialized before the (statically invoked) constructor for `foo` runs to the point where it needs `bar`. 
We could explicitly initiate `bar` in the constructor of `foo`, but we need to know whether `bar` has already been initialized.

Comment: yes, with a function static variable. But in general I would advise avoiding this problem all together and just initialize everything inside the main function.

Comment: Yes: Have a static `initialized` flag for `Bar`, protect it using a asynch lock if necessary?

Comment: I hope you don't have an A->B->A circular dependency here.

Comment: Nope, it is a one-way dependency.

Comment: It's *possible* thanks to the fact that the memory for `bar` is zero-initialized prior to any code running. So you can give `Bar` a data member that the constructor initializes to a non-zero value. The fact that it's possible doesn't make it a good idea, though. If you find `bar` uninitialized then it probably doesn't make sense to initialize it when it's due to be initialized again later on. About the best you could do with the knowledge is abort, so that the programmer knows they need to take steps to fix the initialization order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible, but if you want to see how to implement something that is always initialized before use, look at the implementation of `std::cout`