# Static initialization in one compilation unit

Tags: c++, templates, static

Static initialization is well described subject, [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) and even at this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order)

And everywhere it is written that problem will occurs if there exists different compilation units with related static variables. And if static variables exists in one compilation unit, there shouldn't be problem: they will be initialized in order of their position in file.

But I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    int _data;
    T _obj;
    A(int data) :_data(data){}
};

template <typename T>
class B{
public:
    const static B<T> nullObj;
    B(int data) :_a(new A<T>(data)){}
    A<T> *_a;
};

template <typename T>
class C{
public:
    const static C<T> nullObj;
    C() :_a(nullObj._a){}
    C(bool t) :_a(B<T>::nullObj._a){
        _a->_data++; //FAILS HERE!
    }
    A<T> *_a;
};

template <typename T>
const B<T> B<T>::nullObj(0);

template <typename T>
const C<T> C<T>::nullObj(false);

class _B{};
class  _A{ public: _A(){}; C<_B> g; };

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

And it fails at runtime before entering main() function, because it tries to initialize `const C<T> C<T>::nullObj(false);` **before** `const B<T> B<T>::nullObj(0);` is initialized. Despite their position in one file.

Why does it tries to initialize second static variable before first static variable? Does there exist chapter in C++ Standart where described real situation with sequence of static initialization?

Comment: "Why does it tries to initialize second static variable before first static variable?" There's no "first" and no "second" variable here, it's a pair of templates from which you could produce zero, two, four, six, eight, etc. static variables on template instantiation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, ok, you are right, then question is: "why does it tries to initialize second static template before first one?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ Standard, section 14.7.1 [temp.inst]:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; **in particular, the initialization (and any associated
>   side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist**

---

`C<T>` is instanciated before `B<T>`, so the order of initialization is well defined, and is :

**1)** `const static C<T> nullObj;`

**2)** `const static B<T> nullObj;`

Since `C` constructor dereference `B<T>::nullObj._a`, you have undefined behavior.

**Solution:**

You must use the static member `B<_B>::nullObj` somehow for it to be initialized, e.g. if you do :

```
class _B{};
class _A{ public: _A() : b(B<_B>::nullObj) {}; B<_B> b; C<_B> g; };
```

Then `B<_B>::nullObj` is indeed initialized before `C` constructor needs it

Comment: I modified _A to initialize B<_B> before C<_B> this way: `class  _A{ public: _A() : b(0) {}; B<_B> b; C<_B> g; };` still it fails.

Comment: @Arkady see my edit, you are still not instantiating the static member

Comment: Yes, that solves and explains everything, thank you! But there still is a question: why adding g(0) at constructor initialization list also solves problem? I.e. `b(0), g(0)` - also works.

Comment: Because `g(0)` forces the initialization of `C<T>::nullObj` (note that your previous version was implicitly calling `g()`)

Answer (score 2):

Template *instances* are not defined until they are instantiated. The first time `C<>` is instantiated is in `_A`'s constructor. And `B<>` is instantiated by `C<>`, so `B<_B>` is defined when `C<_B>` is instantiated. Therefore `C<_B>` is before `B<_B>`.

You can add explicit template instantiation `template class B<_B>;` before the definition of `_A`, which I believe should fix the order.

Comment: I checked it. If I change _A to `class  _A{ public: _A() : b(0) {}; B<_B> b; C<_B> g; };` , so B<_B> now have to be initialized before C<_B>, there is still failing.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to run ok if I add `g(0)` to the initialization list. Either there's undefined behaviour or there's a rule which is unknown to me. All of these versions (your original and your new `_A`) work for me with the explicit instantiation (notice that I had a typo originally, it's supposed to be `B<_B>`).

Comment: As I know, order of initialization of class members defined by their appearance in code. So, if `b` goes before `g` in class body, it have to be initialized first, even if in constructor g(0) will be before b(0).
But yes, if I add g(0) after or before b(0), it works. I just wonder why.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that it works with `g(0)` is that it only crashes with `C()` which uses `C<_B>::nullObj`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you made this problem clean for me.

Answer (score 1):

The point is in _A's constructor. As [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) states:

The default constructor for class T is trivial (i.e. performs no action) if all of the following is true:

- **The constructor is not user-provided (that is, implicitly-defined or defaulted)**
- T has no virtual member functions
- T has no virtual base classes
- T has no non-static members with brace-or-equal initializers. (since C++11)
- Every direct base of T has a trivial default constructor
- Every non-static member of class type has a trivial default constructor

This [is not trivially constructible](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_constructible/)

```
class  _A{ public: _A(){} };
```

while this is

```
class  _A{ public: };
```

and in the case of the example this definitely hasn't a trivial constructor:

```
class  _A{ public: _A(){} C<_B> g; };
```

that means the constructor **does perform** initialization routines for the members of the class. As the standard says 14.7.1 [temp.inst]

> the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist

and since the non-trivial constructor just provided us the **use** (not the **need**) for static variables to be initialized, the CRT begins its work and starts initializing

```
const static C<T> nullObj;
```

which in turn dereferences something unitialized and you have undefined behavior.

To solve, as quantdev as stated, either you initialize `B<_B>::nullObj` before this process or change the design of your code.