# C++: Make function treat global variable as const

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following setup:

Foo.cpp

```
class Bar {
public:
    inline Bar() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    inline Bar(int X, int Y, int Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
    const int x, y, z;
};

static Bar globalBar;

static void foo() {
    int x = globalBar.x; // the compiler should assume globalBar is const here!
    ...
}

void almightySetup() {
    globalBar = Bar(meaningOfLife(), complexCalc(), magic());
    startThread(foo); // foo() will NEVER be called before this point!
    // globalBar will NEVER be changed after this point!
}
```

As you can see, it is safe for the compiler to assume that `globalBar` is `const` at the indicated point, because `globalBar`, after setup, will never be changed after that point. Furthermore, `foo()` will not be called before it is setup.

But how can I accomplish this? I've tried using `const_cast<>` but keep getting type error messages. I must be doing something wrong. Is it even possible?

I should add that I am not at liberty to change the function signature of `foo`.

Comment: A compiler does not assume anything. A compiler compiles the code according to what the code says. If an object is declared as `const`, the compiler considers it to be a `const` object. If an object is not declared as `const`, the compiler will not consider it to be a `const` object. The End.

Comment: Why does it matter that the compiler assumes `globalBar` is `const` in `foo()`?

Comment: For optimization reasons. I have very few cycles to play with in this code.

Comment: Agreed with @SamVarshavchik. What you could do is declare it const and assign to it in the declaration. However, beware of doing this with globals since you can easily die in the fire of the [static initialization order fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order). You should consider a singleton pattern, which will allow you to access your global object through a function that returns a const reference.

Comment: Can you make the global variable const and then use a const cast in the setup function to assign to it?  Then it is const for the entire rest of the program

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments! This is the kind of info I need to understand the assumptions that are safe for the compiler to make about const objects.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah -- modifying an object that is defined as const produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker  Good point - I should think before talking.

Comment: Try to find a way to avoid the global. Singleton/Monostate pattern or just pass it around. With globals you surrender such fine grained control.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible as you want it in C++, at least not to my knowledge.  While it would be a godsend in certain situations (such as when working with legacy code that uses tons of globals, or in extremely resource-limited systems), you'll have to make do with something else.

Comment: Thanks @JustinTime but how about my proposed answer below? Is that possible and/or safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a theoretical example. I haven't tested it but would love opinions from C++ experts. Would this work?

```
static Bar globalBar;

static void foo() {
    static const Bar myGlobalBar = globalBar;
    int x = myGlobalBar .x; // the compiler should assume globalBar is const here!
    ...
}
```

Comment: `myGlobalBar` will be `const`, but it will also be a copy of `globalBar`.  Perhaps a `const` reference would work?  I don't believe initialisation order would come back to bite you.