# Visual Studio executing subclass's .cpp before superclass's

Tags: c++

I've got an abstract superclass, `KFilter` with a static map member, `static map<KFILTER_TYPE, FilterFactory*> factories;`. As you can see, I use factories and this map has the respective ones for each subclass by a custom Enum, `KFILTER_TYPE`. Now, I initialize the `factories` map in the cpp file of the superclass:

```
//KFilter.cpp

<KFILTER_TYPE, FilterFactory*> KFilter::factories = <KFILTER_TYPE, FilterFactory*>();
```

To automatically bind the factories, I have a macro, `#define REGISTER_TYPE(filterName, filterENUM)`, which I use at the top of each subclass, like `REGISTER_TYPE(EKFilter, EKF)`. This uses a line which registers the factory of the subclass to the map of the superclass.

However, I get a runtime error, with `Exception thrown: read access violation.`. After durdling around, I've figured this is because the macro executed in the subclass gets called *before* the static map is initialized in the cpp of the superclass. My question is, why does this happen? I thought that the superclass, with its .h and .cpp would compile before the subclasses. Heck, I didn't even include the subclasses in either my main or the superclass header. What gives and how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these factories and registerers stored as global variables?

Comment: static initialization order fiasco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ static initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order)

Comment: @Frank The factor classes are made my a macro that's called in each subclass, they map is a static member of the superclass, not a global variable.

Comment: @SparksH static member variables are global.  The name is scoped to the class but it suffers the same thing as regular global variables.

Comment: @Frank I've tried wrapping the initialization in a function, but where do I call that one? I can't call it outside the class definition.