# How to map different C++ classes to enum class values

Tags: c++, enums, scoped-enums

I produce messages and each is receive by one object, chosen by an `enum class` member:

```
enum class ReceiverID
{
    R1,
    R2,
    MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS
};

struct Msg
{
    ReceiverID _receiverID;
    Data _data;
};
```

The receiving classes are stored in an array. The enum member indexes the array to access the receiving object:

```
void receive(const Msg& msg)
{
    const size_t arrIndex = static_cast<size_t>(msg._receiverID);
    
    if(nullptr == _array[arrIndex])
    {
        _array[arrIndex] = ???  // How do I associate the enum to the class?
    }
    
     _array[arrIndex].processMsg(msg);
}
```

It is possible the receiving object is missing. If this happens I'd like to use the enum to instantiate the missing object. However, this would require mapping the enum values to the receiving object type.

How can I map a class to each enum? (for all enums).

I'd like to generate a compiler error if a new enum is added but without a corresponding receiver class.

UPDATE

The receiving objects are polymorphic and so have a base class. The array is:

```
std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS> _array;
```

(removed `unique_ptr` to simplify question)

Comment: which is the enum member? What is the type of `_array`? It can only hold elements of one type, no?

Comment: since you are storing the receiving objects in an array and did not mention using variants etc. Do all the classes inherit from a base class? Also do all the receiving classes share a signature for the constructor you want to use?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: We need to know `_array` type before the question would be answered.

Comment: @jwezorek Yes they inherit from a base class and the array containers pointers to these. I have updated the question.

Comment: @SergeyA Have updated the question with that info.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is `Base` a base of? I'm having a very hard time to see why the answer isn't simply `_array[arrIndex] = &pMsg;`, but then again I'm having also having a very hard time to follow this rambling question format.

Comment: `_array[arrIndex].processMsg(msg);`  should be `_array[arrIndex]->processMsg(msg);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For on-the-fly creation of objects we could go for some kind of a factory method, e.g.:

```
//In the Base class:
static Base* createReceiver(ReceiverID recvID) //static member function
{
    switch (recvID)
    {
        case ReceiverID::R1: return new R1Receiver();
        case ReceiverID::R2: return new R2Receiver();
        //...
        default: throw std::logic_error("Invalid ReceiverID");
    }
}

//...
void receive(const Msg& msg) except(true)
{
    const size_t arrIndex = static_cast<size_t>(msg._receiverID);
    if(nullptr == _array[arrIndex])
    {
        _array[arrIndex] = Base::createReceiver(msg._receiverID);
    }    
    _array[arrIndex]->processMsg(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: @user997112 You're welcome :) You can adapt it to support `unique_ptr`s (as you mentioned you're using them). Change return type to `unique_ptr<Base>` and replace all `new` with `make_unique()`.

Comment: `_array[arrIndex].processMsg(msg);` should be `_array[arrIndex]->processMsg(msg);`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yea, copied from op's, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a global `std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS> _array;` and then lazily filling it out on demand, I believe the normal thing to do is make it filled out at construction time:

```
std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS>& _array() {
    //use a method to bypass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order
    static std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS> array = make_array();
    return array;
}
std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS> make_array() {
    std::array<Base*, MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS> array;
    array[static_cast<size_t>(R1)] = &myR1ProcessorObject();
    array[static_cast<size_t>(R2)] = &myR2ProcessorObject();
    return array;
}
```

Then your receive method is simple:

```
void receive(const Msg& msg)
{
    const size_t arrIndex = static_cast<size_t>(msg._receiverID);
    assert(arrIndex< MAX_NUM_RECEIVERS);
     _array()[arrIndex].processMsg(msg);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I accepted the other one because I am receiving messages remotely, the objects are very expensive and whilst I will try to instantiate all that is needed, I wanted to check and create any which aren't, on-the-fly. This is why the question focused on the mapping.