# Correct pattern for nested private class that inherit from outer class

Tags: c++, factory, inner-classes

I am trying to implement a pattern in C++ where a nested private class inherits from the outer class and the private class is instantiated via a static factory method in the outer abstract class.

I have this code now, that compiles, but I am not sure whether I did it correctly.

Search.h:

```
namespace ns_4thex {
    class Search {
        private:
            class Implementation;
        public:
            static Search & create();
            virtual int doIt() = 0;
    };
    class Search::Implementation: public Search {
        int doIt();
    };
}
```

Search.cpp:

```
#include "Search.h"
using namespace ns_4thex;
Search & Search::create() {
    return *(new Search::Implementation());
}

int Search::Implementation::doIt() {
    return 0;
}
```

Thought?

Comment: pretty sure that `return *(new Search::Implementation());` will cause a ton of memory leaks

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Isn't it going to be the responsibility of the consumer to call delete on the reference when it is no longer needed?

Comment: This looks like you're trying to create the `pimpl` pattern, and also need to learn [how to use singletons in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for the useful pointer. Yeah, the pimpl patterns seems like an interesting study. I used to program in C++ like 20 years ago, and now I decided to get certified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static factory method always returns a pointer type. So the `create` function should return a pointer or smart pointers in modern c++.

The declaration:

```cpp
static std::unique_ptr<Search> create();
```

The definition:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Search> Search::create() {
  return std::make_unique<Search::Implementation>();
}
```

The complete code may like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
namespace ns_4thex {
class Search {
 private:
  class Implementation;

 public:
  static std::unique_ptr<Search> create();
  virtual int doIt() = 0;
};

class Search::Implementation : public Search {
  int doIt();
};

std::unique_ptr<Search> Search::create() {
  return std::make_unique<Search::Implementation>();
}

int Search::Implementation::doIt() { return 0; }
}  // namespace ns_4thex
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example has potentially a memory leak. The factory pattern should return a pointer type instead of the reference type. The caller using it can free the allocated memory

```
Search* Search::create() {
    return new Search::Implementation();
}
```

Comment: It would better to use `make_unique` and return `unique_ptr` to make the ownership clean.

Comment: So you cannot call delete on a reference using the address of operator (&)?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin If you make your comment an answer, I will make it the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: @4thex The pattern in your code seems interesting, this is the first time I have seen this design, could you please share some use case scenarios?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin It is a pattern I have used in C#. Instead of using new and be tempted to pass the implementation around as arguments, I wanted to basically make that impossible. Only the abstract type will be passed around, and the only way to create an instance would be via the factory method. Alternative implementations can then be easily created later if needed.