Unexpected bloat of .text in Microblaze embedded C++ program when using new/static variables
I'm creating an embedded C++ program for a Microblaze Microcontroller System. The IP only supports up to 128Kb of memory. I want to allocate memory on the heap, but as soon as I use the new keyword, the .text section (code length) instantly bloats by 178Kb (I'm guessing from standard library includes, but I don't recognise a lot of the names).
My questions are:

Is it normal for new to bloat the program so much
If so, what alternatives are there? Is there a way to initialize a class on the heap using malloc?

Example code with/without bloat:
// .text 3,844 B
int main() {
    return 0;
}

// .text 179,020 B
int main() {
    new int;
    return 0;
}

Some of the larger symbols added after adding new:
00005054 l     F .text  000010c0 execute_stack_op
0013614 l     F .text   00003540 d_print_comp_inner
0001b934 g     F .text  00002ff4 _svfprintf_r
00024320 g     F .text  000015f4 _svfiprintf_r
000262c0 g     F .text  000018ec _vfiprintf_r

Edit: This also seems to occur when using local static variables with constructors
class A {
public:
    A(){}
};

// .text 3,804 B
int main() {
    A a;
    return 0;
}

// .text 179,056 B
int main() {
    static A a;
    return 0;
}

System: Windows 11
Target: Microblaze MCS 128Kb, Nexys A7-100T
Toolchain: Vitis 2024.1, mb-g++ 12.2.0, standalone toolchain (no OS)
Flags: mb-g++.exe -isystem <include-dirs> -O2 -mlittle-endian -mno-xl-reorder -mxl-soft-mul -mcpu=v11.0 -DSDT  -MMD -MP -specs=<spec-path> -I<include-path> -Wall -Wextra      -Os      -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -U__clang__ -MD -MT <obj> -MF <obj.d> -o <obj> -c <src-file>
And yes, it is strange that -O2 and -Os are both being set - I can control the -Os, but the -O2 is automatically added by Vitis. Note that -Os -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti were added after comment suggestions - -O0 may be needed to get the new example to work, but -Os also runs into issues in the static example and if the memory is actually used.

Try to build with -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti. I bet the board manual mentions these flags.

My guess: That's probably the exception handling. Using new implies e.g. that it is possible for your program to abort with a std::bad_alloc message. Use the nonthrowing versions of new, i.e. new(std::nothrow) int; and check the result against null to avoid this.

To be honest, I avoid dynamic allocation like the plague on embedded systems to avoid memory fragmentation. I automatically allocate pretty much everything, including arrays of stuff I can dole out pseudo-dynamically as required. A std::list with an allocator that pulls from one of those arrays is very helpful in managing those pseudo-dynamic allocations.

@3CxEZiVlQ No change unfortunately (will look through docs though in case I missed something)

@user17732522 Same with this version

The specific problem I'm facing right now is setting up global variables - ideally I want to access it without passing everywhere, but also avoid initializing globally as it's then hard to control initialization order. Though std::option is always another solution for that case.

I control initialization order with a trick stollen from the Meyers Singleton: type & getwhatever() { static type whatever{arguments}; return whatever; } This is initialized on first use so it never gets out of order but the destruction order is now murky.

Regarding Is there a way to initialize a class on the heap using malloc, allocate yes. Initialize no. You'd have to go C-Style.

Side note: using globals to avoid passing things around can make it easy to write the code, but because everything now has potential side effects, debugging gets harder. Since debugging code is almost always harder than writing code, you make something that's harder even harder to make the easy part even easier. That's usually a terrible trade-off.

sounds like you are asking for a work around to the static initialization order fiasco.  If so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order

In Embedded Systems, the common rule of thumb is not to use dynamic memory and any data structures that use dynamic memory.  For example, if you need a linked list, use an array based linked list, and preallocate the space for the array.  Fragmented memory is not a good thing on embedded systems.

Strangely the static memory trick seems to run into the same issue - for example, the below jumps to 178Kb (but stays small if the constructor is omitted)
class A { public: A(){} }; int main() { static A a; return 0; }
Regarding fragmentation, the classes are really small (8 bytes each), and are mostly to encapsulate the functions. But I appreciate the tip - it's not one I've heard before

int main() { return 0; } pulls in none of the really groovy C++ infrastructure, but the minimum cost of simply having a class instantiated shouldn't be that heavy. Do you see the same jump without the static? Do you have the build optimizing for size? Probably worth an edit to the question to add the toolchain you're using.

If A isn't static the code size stays small. For the above examples I was using -O0 - if I switch to -Os it can optimise out some simple cases, but any actual usage (or local static constructors) still causes a code size jump by the same amount. Got some toolchain details above already, but I'll expand the original post a bit more

Just checking in to see if anyone had answered yet. You've hit a n oddity I'd like to have an answer to in my toolbox should I run into it. I can't see any good language-based reason for this, so I'm thinking it's an implementation detail for a system I'm not familiar enough with and your answer will have to wait until someone who is familiar stumbles over this question. If you happen to find a solution in the meantime, please self-answer. This is exactly the sort of stuff Stack Overflow is for.

Mind you, you might want to rewrite the title to draw attention to what the actual problem is: unexpected bloat of data section with new and static variables.
